# AKHQ: Couldn't find any clusters on your configuration file, please ensure that the configuration file is loaded correctly

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, akhq

My Kafka bootstrap server in Kubernetes is at `hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092`.

I am trying to deploy [AKHQ](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq) in my Kubernetes cluster. Here are my steps:

```bash
helm upgrade \
  akhq \
  akhq \
  --install \
  --repo=https://akhq.io \
  --namespace=hm-akhq \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=my-values.yaml
```

**my-values.yaml**

```yaml
akhq:
  connections:
    hm-kafka:
      properties:
        bootstrap.servers: hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
```

I created this **my-values.yaml** is based on [this](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/blob/dev/helm/akhq/values.yaml#L47-L61). However, I am sure I use it correctly.

Then I port forwarded by `kubectl port-forward service/akhq --namespace=hm-akhq 8080:80`

However, when I open localhost:8080, the page shows

```json
{
  "message": "Couldn't find any clusters on your configuration file, please ensure that the configuration file is loaded correctly",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/",
      "templated": false
    }
  }
}
```

I have read these tickets with same error

- https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/issues/63
- https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/issues/106
- https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/issues/604

But I didn't find any solution inside to solve my issue. Any guide would be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Your linked section of the values is wrong. See the [actual configMap definition](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/blob/dev/helm/akhq/templates/configmap.yaml#L13) (you are missing `configuration`), and compare to the docs for the correct YAML syntax.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, I posted in the answer. The [values.yaml](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/blob/dev/helm/akhq/values.yaml#L21-L61) I linked is correct. However, the comments inside and `akhq.connections` under `secrets` field confused me. `akhq.connections` should be under `configuration` instead in my case as you pointed out. 

Comment: Might be worth a PR to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @OneCrckerteer help! The comments inside this section of [values.yaml](https://github.com/tchiotludo/akhq/blob/dev/helm/akhq/values.yaml#L21-L61) and `akhq.connections` under `secrets` originally confused me:

```yaml
## You can put directly your configuration here... or add java opts or any other env vars
extraEnv: []
# - name: AKHQ_CONFIGURATION
#   value: |
#       akhq:
#         secrets:
#           docker-kafka-server:
#             properties:
#               bootstrap.servers: "kafka:9092"
# - name: JAVA_OPTS
#   value: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password"
# - name: CLASSPATH
#   value: "/any/additional/jars/desired.jar:/go/here.jar"

## Or you can also use configmap for the configuration...
configuration:
  akhq:
    server:
      access-log:
        enabled: false
        name: org.akhq.log.access

##... and secret for connection information
existingSecrets: ""
# name of the existingSecret
secrets: {}
#  akhq:
#    connections:
#      my-cluster-plain-text:
#        properties:
#          bootstrap.servers: "kafka:9092"
#        schema-registry:
#          url: "http://schema-registry:8085"
#          type: "confluent"
#          basic-auth-username: basic-auth-user
#          basic-auth-password: basic-auth-pass
#        connect:
#          - name: "my-connect"
#            url: "http://connect:8083"
#            basic-auth-username: basic-auth-user
#            basic-auth-password: basic-auth-pass
```

`akhq.connections` should be under `configuration` instead of `secrets`. And here is the final working version:

```bash
helm upgrade \
  akhq \
  akhq \
  --install \
  --repo=https://akhq.io \
  --namespace=hm-akhq \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=my-values.yaml
```

**my-values.yaml**

```yaml
configuration:
  akhq:
    connections:
      hm-kafka:
        properties:
          bootstrap.servers: hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092
        schema-registry:
          type: confluent
          url: http://confluent-schema-registry.hm-confluent-schema-registry.svc:8081
```